# Braintree returning "91569 paymentMethodNonce does not contain a valid payment instrument type" for ApplePay - Why?

Tags: php, ios, paypal, braintree, applepay

I recently migrated my server and all of it's files to a new machine. In the process, something has changed with my setup and I'm having some payment issues with Braintree.

I have an iOS client that accepts PayPal, Credit Card, and ApplePay and connects to my server via PHP as needed. It's been working perfectly fine before server the migration. Now, PayPal and Credit Card still works fine in production, but ApplePay no longer works.

When I pass a nonce up to the payments.php with payment_method_nonce= when using ApplePay, I am getting the following error returned:

```
[0] => Braintree\Error\Validation Object
        (
            [_attribute:Braintree\Error\Validation:private] => paymentMethodNonce
            [_code:Braintree\Error\Validation:private] => 91569
            [_message:Braintree\Error\Validation:private] => paymentMethodNonce does not contain a valid payment instrument type.
        )
```

I know for a fact the issue isn't in the iOS code, because it's been live for quite a while now and has been working just fine. I'm using a valid real credit card in Apple Wallet on a normal production iPhone device. I have noticed since the server migration I've gotten zero ApplePay sales because of this issue.

This error started happening when I migrated the server and so there must be some configuration error on the PHP side in some way. I've done the install with composer.phar and just copied over my payments.php page from my other server, so there are no changes to anything that I can tell.

Ideas? Why wouldn't an ApplePay payment nonce "not contain a valid payment instrument type"? Obviously any ApplePay transaction would include a valid payment type (such as Visa)... so what is going on?

The one major change between the two servers was the old one was on PHP 5.4 and the new one is on 5.6. I also have all the web files (including payments.php) on a D: drive rather than a C: drive now.

Comment: Please close. Question is highly unlikely to be relevant to others as the issue was on Braintree's side.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I know this was a long time ago, but we're having the same issue now. We've debugged everything we can think of, and think this might be happening to us... can you share any insight about what the resolution was, or what Braintree had to do to fix?

Comment: Contact Braintree. It was an issue on their end for my specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

Do you have a sandbox environment configured? If so, and if your sandbox has the same issue, you might try short circuting your server to execute transactions against a [fake-apple-pay-visa-nonce](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#alternate-payment-method-nonces) rather than the nonce you receive from your client to help isolate the issue to client-server interaction rather than the server-Braintree interaction.

It might also be worth investigating whether the nonce your client receives from Braintree is the same as the nonce your server receives from your client - if your server is receiving a `nil` or default nonce, that might explain an invalid nonce error.

Lastly, double check that Apple Pay is still [enabled in your gateway](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/apple-pay/configuration/ios/v4#apple-pay-certificate-request-and-provisioning). There is a certification process associated with AP functionality, which a server migration may or may not interrupt.

As this is an issue in production, I would absolutely recommend reaching out to [Braintree support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com) regardless of the outcome of your troubleshooting.

Comment: nonce is not nil on the server and is showing what the client passes to it. Just checked the POST. Apple Pay still enabled in the gateway. I'm doing the Sandbox testing and fake-apple-pay-visa-nonce right now and will post another comment with what I find.

I've emailed support but haven't heard from them yet.

Comment: Sandbox works just fine using a normal generated nonce with a dummy Apple Pay credit card. Switched back to production and got the error again with my personal credit card in my Apple Wallet.

Comment: All I am switching is the `environment`, `merchantId`, `publicKey`, and `privateKey` on the PHP side and the `clientToken` and `merchantIdentifier` on the iOS side between production/sandbox. Sandbox works, production does not.

Comment: Reverted back to the exact same PHP version and "payment" directory of files as my original server, still the same issue.

Comment: Talk to support, problem was on your end, fixed now.